# How to navigate from one html page to another in IBM MobileFirst?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

1)I need to navigate from one page to another in IBM mobile First app as soon as I click the button.
2)Is there any document that clearly explains how to develop an app using eclipse (IBM mobile first 8.0)?

Can anyone please help me

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600
Windows 7

Comment: which platform you want to use such as jQuery, AngularJS, Ionic etc

Comment: I want to use jQuery .

Comment: you mean JQuery-Mobile?

Comment: yes ..I am new to IBM mobile first ,so thought using jQuery itself

Answer (score 2):

1) To learn how to develop a hybrid Angular app in MobileFirst 8.0, please see this lab. There is no longer the MobileFirst hybrid, and will be moving toward Cordova, Ionic, Angular.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/labs/developers/8.0/intro/

2) To develop an app with eclipse in MobileFirst 8.0, please follow this blogpost. There's a plugin you can download from Eclipse marketplace.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/ibm-mobilefirst-studio-8-0-plugin-for-eclipse-now-available/

Comment: Do you mean I can't use Jquery for navigation ??

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst is a Single-page application (SPA).
There are several ways to navigate in a single-page application. Usually it will depend on the framework you are using to build your application such as jQuery, AngularJS, Ionic etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Javascript worked for me

window.location("your html page path");